# create 100% stack bar plots with ggplots

Tags: r, data-visualization

```
data <- read.table(text = "    None  Few Some All mean
AA1   20  20 30 30 2.4
AA2   10  30 40 20 3.5 
AA3   30  30 30 10 2.8
 
",sep = "",header = TRUE)
```

and I want to create a 100% stack bar chart like below
[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `ggplot`? Or anything will do?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to plot if you get the data in long format -

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  select(-mean) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rowname) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  mutate(fill = -row_number()) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(rowname, value, fill = fill, label = paste0(value, '%')) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack') + 
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = '', y = '') + 
  guides(fill = 'none')
```

[image]